# PrimeNG Table Sorting - Only show icons when sorted

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I have a pretty standard PrimeNG table that has sortable columns.  But by default, the sort icons appear.  Is it possible to only show the sort icons when the column has been sorted?

```
<p-table [value]="rows" styleClass="p-datatable-striped"   responsiveLayout="scroll">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th pSortableColumn="id">ID<p-sortIcon field="id"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="name">Study Name<p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="status">Status<p-sortIcon field="status"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="createdOn">Created Date<p-sortIcon field="createdOn"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="updatedOn">Last Updated Date<p-sortIcon field="updatedOn"></p-sortIcon></th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
    <tr>
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>{{row.status}}</td>
        <td>{{row.createdOn | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
        <td>{{row.updatedOn | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this css. It will hide the sort when it is not applied on a column!

```
.ui-sortable-column-icon.pi.pi-fw.pi-sort {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-r81qa5)

Comment: Ended up needing p-sortable-column-icon.pi.pi-fw.pi-sort-alt , but you put me on the right path.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `visibility: hidden` I use `display: none` because hidden elements still occupy some space, causing column header to misalign.